# How do you find if a HTREEITEM has a children and that they are expanded?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

Given a node in a CTreeCtrl, I'd like to determine if that node has children and if they are expanded.  Is there a way of doing that?

Comment: Use CTreeCtrl::GetChildItem() and GetNextItem() to enumerate the child nodes.  Use GetItemState() to check their state, you want to test for TVIS_EXPANDED.  Use the MSDN Library for usage notes and example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CTreeCtrl::ItemHasChildren](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0987se1.aspx)

Retrieving the expanded state of an Item : [CTreeCtrl::GetItemState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzs9sf8w.aspx) with nStateMask set to TVIS_EXPANDED

Comment: Thanks, I did check there before but I didn't see it before.  I don't always find the MSDN help very user friendly. :/